# How to set global variable inside computed property in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, computed-properties

I have  this radio button code displayed on the header part of the site I was working on

```
  <v-radio-group v-model="changeQualityVideo" :mandatory="false">
    <v-radio color="success" :name="1" :label="tt('Global')" :value="1" v-bind:class="[quality === 'hd' ? 'is--active' : '']"></v-radio>
    <v-radio color="success" :name="2" :label="tt('Local')" :value="2" v-bind:class="[quality === 'sd' ? 'is--active' : '']"></v-radio>
  </v-radio-group>
```

The purpose of this feature is to set the video source URL. If the user chooses the global, the quality will be HD on the current page's video and on the rest of the site's videos. If the user chooses the local, the quality will be SD on the current page's video and on the rest of the site's videos.

However, I can't seem to make my computed property make the change of URL to be site wide. It only changes on the current page but not on other pages.

My computed property is this:

```
computed: {
    changeQualityVideo: {
        get: function () {
          let _s = this
          return _s.$store.state.videoQuality
        },
        set: function (changeQualityVideo) {
          let _s = this
          _s.$store.state.videoQuality = changeQualityVideo
        }
  },
  reloadPlayer: function () {
    return this.$store.state.currentTableInfo.TableName.split('-')[1]
  }
},
watch: {
    changeQualityVideo (value) {
        let _s = this
        let sources = ''
        if (value === 2) {
            this.$store.state.urls.video_url = 'http://local.stream.com/'
            sources = {src: this.$store.state.urls.video_url + 'hls/mds' + _s.reloadPlayer + 'table1.m3u8', type: 'application/x-mpegURL'}
        } else if (value === 1) {
            this.$store.state.urls.video_url = 'http://global.stream.com/'
            sources = {src: this.$store.state.urls.video_url + 'hls/mds' + _s.reloadPlayer + 'table1.m3u8', type: 'application/x-mpegURL'}
        }
        _s.$store.state.hlsPlayer.src(sources)
        _s.$store.state.hlsPlayer.load()
        _s.$store.state.hlsPlayer.play()
  }
}
```

My theory is that I need to put the get property inside the watch property. Or the get property inside the watch clause. But both not sure.

UPDATE: 
the store.js is this:

```
const store = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      urls: {
    <video>_api: <api>
    video_url: 
      },
    hlsPlayer: null
}
```

Comment: can you post your `store.js`

Comment: @RooshanAkthar Updated my post. thanks